# A twice derivable bijective function defined on [0,1] such that f(α)=1/3 and f(f(β))=1/3.

Tags: calculus

Consider **twice derivable bijective function** defined on $[0,1]$ such that

$f(α)=1/3$ and $f(f(β))=1/3$.

If $f''(x)>0 $∀$ x∈[0,1/2)$ and $f''(x)<0 ∀ x∈[1/2,1)$ with $f(1/2)=1/2$.

Then does $β>α$ imply $f(x)$ is an **increasing function**?

**My approach:** Now since $f(x)$ is twice derivable and bijective , it is a monotone.

Now let $β>α$ . If  $f(x)$ is an **increasing function** then that implies

$f(β)>   f(α)$ which means **$α$ should be greater than $1/3$**.

Now if I can prove $α>1/3$ , then my assumption that $f(x)$ is increasing would be correct .

But I have failed to prove the above .

**On a side note :** How can I bring the fact that $f′(x)$  is increasing from $[0,1/2)$ and decreasing from $(1/2,1]$ and $f(1/2)=1/2$ into play ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**$f$ is indeed increasing.**

Let's prove it by contradiction supposing that $f$ is decreasing. As $f$ is bijective, it is injective. Then $f(\alpha)=f(f(\beta))=1/3$ implies $f(\beta)=\alpha$. Also as $f(1/2) = 1/2$ and $f(\alpha) = 1/3 < 1/2$, we have $\alpha > 1/2$.

The hypothesis $\alpha < \beta$ with $f$ decreasing implies $1/3 = f(\alpha) > f(\beta) = \alpha$, in contradiction with what we got at previous paragraph.

*Indeed the hypothesis on $f^{\prime \prime}$ is useless.*

Comment: I was expecting more of a proof by counter example from you but this works too ! . Thank you .